# How do you say weekend in Chinese using the 星期 form?

Tags: vocabulary, word-requests, phrase, comparison, phrase-request

I know that weekend in Chinese is generally translated as 周末.

Is there a way to say weekend by *adding* something to *星期* like **星期末**? Or the only phrase for weekend is 周末?

Comment: Not the answer: Don't ask new question (and answer the question) in [comment](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). It's fine to ask a question if it is a question; despite of it's small or not. :)

Comment: Hmm... 天末, 月末, 期末, 季末, 年末, 世纪末 = "end of the [day/month/semester/season/year/century]".  (There's even 明末 = "end of the Ming dynasty" etc.)  I'd be surprised if 星期末 doesn't similarly mean "end of the week", even if it is uncommon.

Comment: 星期末 does indeed mean *weekend*, it's just incredibly uncommon. I googled it and a cursory look at the stats turns up about 200,000 hits.

Comment: @Becky李蓓 I had never heard 天末 A google search suggests "前天天末" got 0 results, "昨天天末" got 1 result. "今天天末" got 1 result (plus some unrelated results).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

星期X can only refer to a specific day in a week. 星期六=Saturday, 星期日/星期天=Sunday

周末 refers to Saturday and Sunday together, which is the weekend.

Comment: Wouldn't the logic of 星期 = week and 末 = end and therefore, 星期末 = weekend be correct?

Comment: @aymusbond People simply don't say it like that. Languages don't always follow the logic. Although, if you do use 星期末 in a conversation, people would probably understand you using the same logic, but it takes a lot of effort and they would find it weird.

Answer (score 1):

How about 星期六、日？
Weekdays can be combined like 星期一、三、五. It might be an alternative to 周末? 
Looking forward to other input from members.